# How to download Moodle 2.2.3+?

Tags: moodle

I am trying to analyze what changes were made to a Moodle site by running a diff on the filesystem with a fresh copy of Moodle. However, I was only able to download 2.2.3 from the Moodle site here https://download.moodle.org/stable22/

The site that I am working on is showing the version as 2.2.3+ (note the plus at the end), and there seem to be changes between the two versions. The release date is also a month later (May vs. June). Is there a place I can download the 2.2.3+ version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking out the tag v2.2.4 on the Moodle repository

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/v2.2.4

Then do a `git log version.php` to see if you can find the commit for the version you wanted.

The just `git checkout xxxxx` the commit that is the same version.

UPDATE : Actually you can do that on github

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/commits/v2.2.4/version.php